# Read remote properties

Tags: eclipse, plugins, properties, rcp

First of all, Hello everyone(/world) !

I am making an Eclipse RCP app' who needs to inspect some *.properties* located in some plugins who's Id I know at runtime.

I'd like to know if there is an *easy* way to read them, for example I know that in my plugin *org.anyname.myplugins.***mypluginthatrocks*** I have a file named **myawsomeproperties**.properties*, how can I open it and read it easyly with a sort of getter/setter system like

```
String getInProperties(String fileNameOrPath,String myPropertieId)
void setInProperties(String fileNameOrPath,String myPropertieId,String myPropertieValue)
```

or

```
String getInProperties(File file,String myPropertieId)
void setInProperties(File file,String myPropertieId,String myPropertieValue)
```

or any other mean in that type if you get what I mean ...

Thanks in advance ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if these are juste plain old properties, there is the good old [ResourceBundle](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?java/util/ResourceBundle.html) that will do the trick.

But, if you would like to do it, IMHO, a little bit cleaner, and in a more Eclipse oriented mind, I would suggest that you create a class that you use the NLS class, as [explained here](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/message_bundles.html).

Comment: I get the "NLS missing message: tamiflu in: com.example.rcpapp" and can't figure how to get rid of it...

I have followed the example in the eclipse help center.
I have a messages.properties file in my plugin's root folder,
I made a Messages class and all.

I am surely missing something but what ? :/

Comment: If this is the only message you get, it sounds like you defined a "tamiflu" field in your class but forgot to create the corresponding property in your property file.

Comment: No no I did create a tamiflu field in my messages.properties that is the puzzling point to me :/

Comment: That's what I said. It exists in your class but not in your messages.properties. So while the loader try to find the corresponding key in the property file, it ends up with this logging message (and same for the value of the field in your class)

Comment: No no no ^^ My mistake, when I said :"I did create a tamiflu FIELD in my messages.properties" it was not the right term (excuse my english, french language education system has tons defaults"). What I meant is that I did create a line in my messages.properties FILE (with a text editor) containing "tamiflu=Out Of Stock." ... Hope I made myself clear this time :s

Comment: Hum, this is strange... If it is not too sensitive data, you can send me your plugin code (olivier.hubaut+stackoverflow@gmail.com) so that I can have a look.

Comment: Thanks I finally made it thanks to you, thanks for your time and all your help !